# Bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ s.t $\phi(n)\ne n^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Is it possible to find a bijection $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ,\quad\phi(n)\ne n^2$
>
> If it is not, how to prove, $\forall \phi\in \mathcal{L(\mathbb{N})},\;\forall N\in \mathbb{N},\exists p>N, \text{s.t.}\quad\phi(p)=p^2 $
>
> (with $\mathcal{L(\mathbb{N})}$ the set of all bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N} $

Comment: I am tempted to claim that $\phi(p)=p-1$ for all primes $p$, but I should resist to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Put $\phi(1)=2, \phi(2)=1$ and $\phi(n)=n$ for all $n\geq 3$.

Comment: @Martin  I thought it was a clever question, but it is not  thanks,